# Usar función array_map() para hacer operaciones con arreglos

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando con dos arreglos los cuales tienen la siguiente estructura

Arreglo de datos

```
    $arrDatos = array(
  array(
    array("Clave0-1(a)" => "Dato0-1(a)", "Clave0-2(b)" => "Dato0-2(b)", "Clave0-3(c)" => "Dato0-3(c)"),
    array("Clave0-1(d)" => "Dato0-1(d)", "Clave0-2(e)" => "Dato0-2(e)", "Clave0-3(f)" => "Dato0-3(f)"),
    array("Clave0-1(g)" => "Dato0-1(g)", "Clave0-2(h)" => "Dato0-2(h)", "Clave0-3(i)" => "Dato0-3(i)")
  ),
  array(
    array("Clave1-1(a)" => "Dato1-1(a)", "Clave1-2(b)" => "Dato1-2(b)", "Clave1-3(c)" => "Dato1-3(c)"),
    array("Clave1-1(d)" => "Dato1-1(d)", "Clave1-2(e)" => "Dato1-2(e)", "Clave1-3(f)" => "Dato1-3(f)"),
    array("Clave1-1(g)" => "Dato1-1(g)", "Clave1-2(h)" => "Dato1-2(h)", "Clave1-3(i)" => "Dato1-3(i)")
  ),
  array(
    array("Clave2-1(a)" => "Dato2-1(a)", "Clave2-2(b)" => "Dato2-2(b)", "Clave2-3(c)" => "Dato2-3(c)"),
    array("Clave2-1(d)" => "Dato2-1(d)", "Clave2-2(e)" => "Dato2-2(e)", "Clave2-3(f)" => "Dato2-3(f)"),
    array("Clave2-1(g)" => "Dato2-1(g)", "Clave2-2(h)" => "Dato2-2(h)", "Clave2-3(i)" => "Dato2-3(i)")
  ),
);
```

Arreglo de encabezados

```
$arrEncabezados = array("Encabezado1", "Encabezado2", "Encabezado3");
```

Lo que necesito hacer es que cada valor del arreglo de encabezados sustituya a las claves de los arreglos internos y que quede de la siguiente manera

Arreglo final esperado

```
  array(
[0] => array(
  [0] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato0-1[a] 
    [Encabezado2] => Dato0-2[b] 
    [Encabezado3] => Dato0-3[c]
  )  
  [1] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato0-1[d] 
    [Encabezado2] => Dato0-2[e] 
    [Encabezado3] => Dato0-3[f]
  )
  [2] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato0-1[g]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato0-2[h]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato0-3[i]
  )
)
[1] => array(
  [0] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato1-1[a]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato1-2[b]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato1-3[c],
  )
  [1] => array(   
    [Encabezado1] => Dato1-1[d]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato1-2[e]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato1-3[f]
  )  
  [2] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato1-1[g]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato1-2[h]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato1-3[i]
  )
)
[2] => array(
  [0] => array(
    [Encabezado1] => Dato2-1[a]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato2-2[b]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato2-3[c]
  )
  [1] => array(  
    [Encabezado1] => Dato2-1[d]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato2-2[e]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato2-3[f]
  )
  [2] => array(  
    [Encabezado1] => Dato2-1[g]
    [Encabezado2] => Dato2-2[h]
    [Encabezado3] => Dato2-3[i]
  )  
)
 )
```

Lo que busco es que conserve la misma estructura pero las claves sean remplazadas, estoy ya lo logre haciendo dos ciclos foreach de la siguiente manera

```
    $matrix = array();
$valoresFinal = array();
  foreach ($arrDatos as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
      $matrix[$k] = array_combine($arrEncabezados, $v);          
      $valoresFinal[$k] = $matrix;
    }
  }
```

Pero esto solo me devuelve los datos del últimos 3 arreglos es decir "Dato2-1(a)" hasta "Datos2-1(i)". Intente usar la función array_map() para que esto se aplicara a cada posición del arreglo de datos de la siguiente manera

```
  function combinarValores($arrDatos, $arrEncabezados){
$matrizFinal = array();
  foreach($arrDatos as $clave => $valor){
    foreach($valor as $c => $v){
      return $matrizFinal = array_combine($arrEncabezados, $v);
    }
  }
 }
```

Pero me da el siguiente mensaje `Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in` Pero no entiendo porque me da este error si los parámetros son los mismos arreglos.

Adicional al emparejamiento que busco hacer, también debo realizar otras operaciones con el arreglo resultante y lo que mas me interesa es que conserve en todo momento la estructura que tiene, es por ello que buscaba hacerlo con array_map()

Espero que me puedan orientar a como usar esta función o si hay otra forma de hacerlo. Les agradezco de antemano sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo te falta agregar `$key` como primer índice:

```
$valoresFinal = array();
foreach ($arrDatos as $key => $value)
   foreach ($value as $k => $v)
      $valoresFinal[$key][$k] = array_combine($arrEncabezados, $v);
```

Comment: Intente usar esta solución para otras operaciones que realizo sobre el arreglo resultante pero no me funcionaban, sin embargo después de analizarlo me di cuenta de que la clave es asignar el nuevo arreglo de la siguiente manera `$valoresFinal[$key][$k]` esto permite hacer las operaciones a cada arreglo interno, pero al mismo tiempo mantiene a estos arreglos "separados"